# Opening file from Docker Container in Python/Django Web App

Tags: python, django, docker

I have create a docker container which specifies

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Inside my Django web app, I try to access

```
file_path = '/usr/src/app/management_app/mock/printable-profile.json'

File "/usr/src/app/management_app/urls/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
app_1  |     from ..views import views
app_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/management_app/views/views.py", line 13, in <module>
app_1  |     json_data = open(file_path)
app_1  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/src/app/management_app/mock/printable-profile.json'
```

The container was built correctly. I accessed the container file system by creating a snapshot and running

```
$ docker run -t -i mgmtsnapshot /bin/bash
```

And I can confirm the file exists at the required path. Is there a problem with calling `open()` inside a docker container? Or what else is causing the `file not found` error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mounting /usr/src/app as a volume from the host? If yes, you probably rather run into permission issues, since the host enforces the uid/guid/permissions and if your **python application runs under user X**, but the host defined uid=14 which is noth userX, but also `u=r,g=,o=` as permissions, you cannot access it. Ensure, you do either fix the permission issues on the host by losing them up (ugly) or use tools which can offer you user-ownership mapping on sync, like http://docker-sync.io

Comment: thanks, I have been looking into possible permission restrictions as a cause. I found yesterday, that if I tear down the docker container, remove the image, compose rm, then up --build, and with the file name using an _ instead of a hyphen it actually works. Not sure why but it just does...

Comment: You should answer your own question then, or at least the solution. I could not get what you actually mean here